# MYSQL fulltext search / Ignore Quotation marks

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

I have an item in our mysql database with the title of

KELLOGG's corn flakes

I have a fulltext index on this column and would like to bring this item back when i search for KELLOGG's

I first thought of using a the wildcard

```
SELECT title
FROM products mp 
WHERE MATCH (mp.title) AGAINST (  '+KELLOGG*s*'   IN BOOLEAN MODE )
```

However this example has the obvious problem of bringing anything back with an s in the title!!

Is there anyway of ignoring the quotation mark completely?

Thanks very much guys!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the escape character -- \ -- before the apostrophe.

```
SELECT title FROM products mp WHERE MATCH (mp.title) AGAINST ( '+KELLOGG\'s' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```